# How to renumber group id sequentially in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse

I am trying to rename grouped unique id sequentially using `dplyr` in `R`.
There are five columns in the data frame as below.

```
## Load package if necessary
library(tidyverse)

## Set data frame
df <- data.frame(
    hid=c(10001,10001,10001,10001,10002,10002,10002,10002,10002,
          10003,10003,10003,10003,10003,10003,10004,10004,10004,10004,10004),
    mid=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5),
    tmc=c(010,01010,0,01020,010,010,010,010,010,010,010,010,0,010,010,010,0,01010,010,01010),
    thc=c(010,01010,0,02030,010,020,020,020,030,010,010,010,0,020,030,010,0,02020,030,04040),
    mdc=c(000,01010,0,02020,000,010,010,010,010,000,000,010,0,010,020,000,0,02020,010,01010),
    itc=c(010,01010,0,02020,020,020,020,020,020,010,010,010,0,020,020,010,0,02020,020,02020)
    )
```

Unique ids are given to each row being grouped by some columns: `tmc`, `thc`, `mdc` and `itc`.

```
## Add unique id grouped by tmc, thc, mdc and itc
df.id <- df %>% mutate(id=as.numeric(interaction(tmc,thc,mdc,itc)))
```

As it does not give sequential ids, I need to rename it.
However, I could not find solution for that. The conditions are:

- If `tmc`, `thc`, `mdc` and `itc` are all 0, `id` is set as `0` (I do not know the reason but `interaction` gives `1` for such recoreds in my data frame)
- Other ids should be sequentially renamed but need to keep its group. (if `id`s are set as `4,8,2,2,8`, it should be renamed as `1,2,3,3,2`)

Followings scripts show what I am doing currently. `id` is temporary id obtained from `interaction` function but I need to obtain sequential id indicated in `id.desired` column.

```
## Replace unique id sequentially
## IT DOES NOT GIVE DESIRED OUTPUT
# df.id %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(id2=seq_along(id))

## Desired id is shown in `id.desired`
## `id` is the ones obtained from `interaction` function, which are not set sequentially
     hid   mid   tmc   thc   mdc   itc    id   id.desired
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 10001     1    10    10     0    10   166     1
 2 10001     2  1010  1010  1010  1010   595     2
 3 10001     3     0     0     0     0     1     0
 4 10001     4  1020  2030  2020  2020   796     3
 5 10002     1    10    10     0    20   326     4
 6 10002     2    10    20    10    20   362     5
 7 10002     3    10    20    10    20   362     5
 8 10002     4    10    20    10    20   362     5
 9 10002     5    10    30    10    20   366     6
10 10003     1    10    10     0    10   166     1
11 10003     2    10    10     0    10   166     1
12 10003     3    10    10    10    10   198     7
13 10003     4     0     0     0     0     1     0
14 10003     5    10    20    10    20   362     5
15 10003     6    10    30    20    20   398     8
16 10004     1    10    10     0    10   166     1
17 10004     2     0     0     0     0     1     0
18  1004     3  1010  2020  2020  2020   791     9
19 10004     4    10    30    10    20   366     6
20 10004     5  1010  4040  1010  2020   767    10
```

Any suggestions?
I prefer to use `dplyr` in this operation.

I received some suggestions in the previous question, however it is not the same structure in this case (`dummy` field does not exist in current data frame).
[How to renumber result of intersection/group_indices in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160387/how-to-renumber-result-of-intersection-group-indices-in-r)

Comment: Why is line 18 `id.desired` lower than line 20 `id.desired` when the `id` suggests otherwise? I am unclear about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using the `tidyverse`. Notice that I did not use the `interaction` function. Instead, I used the `group_indices` function from `dplyr` to create the group index and then convert to factor and change the levels based on the occurrence order in the column. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter_at(vars(tmc, thc, mdc, itc), any_vars(. != 0)) %>%
  mutate(id = group_indices(., tmc, thc, mdc, itc)) %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(factor(id, levels = unique(id)))) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = names(df)) %>%
  replace_na(list(id = 0))
df2
#      hid mid  tmc  thc  mdc  itc id
# 1  10001   1   10   10    0   10  1
# 2  10001   2 1010 1010 1010 1010  2
# 3  10001   3    0    0    0    0  0
# 4  10001   4 1020 2030 2020 2020  3
# 5  10002   1   10   10    0   20  4
# 6  10002   2   10   20   10   20  5
# 7  10002   3   10   20   10   20  5
# 8  10002   4   10   20   10   20  5
# 9  10002   5   10   30   10   20  6
# 10 10003   1   10   10    0   10  1
# 11 10003   2   10   10    0   10  1
# 12 10003   3   10   10   10   10  7
# 13 10003   4    0    0    0    0  0
# 14 10003   5   10   20   10   20  5
# 15 10003   6   10   30   20   20  8
# 16 10004   1   10   10    0   10  1
# 17 10004   2    0    0    0    0  0
# 18 10004   3 1010 2020 2020 2020  9
# 19 10004   4   10   30   10   20  6
# 20 10004   5 1010 4040 1010 2020 10
```

Comment: Thank you, it is quite simple and worked out perfectly without complex operations. I could learn new ideas 1) renumber technique referring to factor level of each element and 2) re-joining dropped rows using `by=names(df)` to replicate original row sets. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to interpret the `id.desired` column but here is an example based on the two conditions and using data.table:

```
 require(data.table)   
 df = data.table(df)   
 df[tmc != 0 & thc != 0 & mdc != 0 & itc != 0, ID := 1:.N, by = .(tmc, thc, mdc, itc)]
 df[is.na(ID), ID := 0]
```

Comment: Thank you but as I have not used `data.table`, I prefer to use `dplyr` in possible (I edited the post).
`id.desired` should be numberd in ascending order except for records of which `tmc,thc,mdc,itc` are all zero (I call it as `all-zero` records). `all-zero` records should set as `0` in `id.desired`.  
Thus, if `id`s are ordered as `4,3,8,3,1 (this is all-zero record),3,1,9`, it should be renamed as `1,2,3,2,0,4,5,6`.  
Though `id.desired` are renamed in ascending order, it still need to identify group obtained from `interaction` (thus, two `3`s in above example are renamed as `2`).

Answer (score 0):

*(edited mutate based on your clarification in comments)*
Here are the two things I tried to do:

1. To ensure that id = 0 when certain variables are 0, I used if_else in the mutate function with the specific conditions you specified.
2. To get `id.desired` I used dense_rank() function.

Here is the code based on the dataset you shared:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(id = if_else(tmc == 0 & thc == 0  & mdc == 0 & itc == 0, 0,
                       as.numeric(interaction(tmc, thc, mdc, itc, lex.order = TRUE)))) %>% 
   mutate(id.desired = dense_rank(id) - 1)
```

The output looks like this

```
    hid   mid  tmc  thc  mdc  itc id   id.desired
1  10001   1   10   10    0   10 227          1
2  10001   2 1010 1010 1010 1010 519          7
3  10001   3    0    0    0    0   0          0
4  10001   4 1020 2030 2020 2020 775         10
5  10002   1   10   10    0   20 228          2
6  10002   2   10   20   10   20 258          4
7  10002   3   10   20   10   20 258          4
8  10002   4   10   20   10   20 258          4
9  10002   5   10   30   10   20 283          5
10 10003   1   10   10    0   10 227          1
11 10003   2   10   10    0   10 227          1
12 10003   3   10   10   10   10 232          3
13 10003   4    0    0    0    0   0          0
14 10003   5   10   20   10   20 258          4
15 10003   6   10   30   20   20 288          6
16 10004   1   10   10    0   10 227          1
17 10004   2    0    0    0    0   0          0
18 10004   3 1010 2020 2020 2020 550          8
19 10004   4   10   30   10   20 283          5
20 10004   5 1010 4040 1010 2020 595          9
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems nice but I need some updates if possible:  
**1.** Sorry for my wrong explanation: I need `0` for all-zero records, not `1`.  
**2.** I prefer to have _sequential_ `id.desired` to understand distribution of unique id easily. I mean that `id.desired` should start from zero except for `all-zero` records of which value is `0`.  
**3.** `dense_rank` function is good but it seems not to fulfill the second point in my comment (it does not return sequential number). Also it may rename `0`, which is given to `all-zero` records, to other value.
Sorry I cannot break lines...

Comment: If you subtract 1 from from `id.desired` will that achieve your objective? `dense_rank` has given a sequential rank based on numerical order of `id` variable, so the sequentiality problem should be solved as well...or have I misunderstood your requirement?

Comment: I have made an edit in the answer based on the clarification you provided. If you want to arrange `id.desired` in ascending order you can add `%>% arrange(id.desired)` at the end of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your update, but updated `id.desired` `7,0,10,2,4,4,4,5,1,1,3,0,4,6,1,0,8,5,9` should be `1,0,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,0,4,8,6,0,9,5,10`. `id.desired` should start from `1` except for `all-zero` records. If a new number is appeared at the first time, it is given `1`, then, another new number is appeared, it is given `2`. Ascending order in temporary `id` does not have any meaning in its order but just used to identify groups.

Comment: also, i do not prefer to use 'arrange' function because each record have other grouping factors: 'hid' and 'mid'. The former is a kind of household id and the latter is an indovidual id. Thus, i would not want to change order of data frame by 'arrange' to keep consistency.